# Find record in past X days

Tags: mongodb

Im trying to get recordd of past 7 days in the discussions collection but it wont return me any records at all

This is what Im using to query

```
db.discussions.find( { "date_added": { $gte: new Date((new Date().getTime() - (15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))) } } );
```

And the date_added field is ISODate

```
"date_added" : ISODate("2017-06-14T12:49:14Z")
```

I've tried searching for the solution online but I havent found anything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find records from 7 days ago from now in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29524555/find-records-from-7-days-ago-from-now-in-mongodb)

Comment: Not a duplicate, I've tried using their solutions, nothing worked out for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks valid.

I have created a collection with these two documents:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b2a55e574088f47d0faa0b"),
    "name" : "before",
    "date_added" : ISODate("2017-08-31T12:49:14.000Z")
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b2a56c574088f47d0faa0f"),
    "name" : "after",
    "date_added" : ISODate("2017-09-07T12:49:14.000Z")
}
```

And I have run this query:

```
db.getCollection('sample').find(
    {"date_added": 
         { 
            // (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) is 7 days of millis
            $gte: new Date((new Date().getTime() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))) 
        }
    })
```

This is the same form of query as you are using and it returns **one** document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b2a56c574088f47d0faa0f"),
    "name" : "after",
    "date_added" : ISODate("2017-09-07T12:49:14.000Z")
}
```

Running that query with `.explain()` clearly shows that the parsed query includes the correct derived value for the `date_added` predicate:

```
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "date_added" : {
            "$gte" : ISODate("2017-09-01T14:16:45.489Z")
        }
    }
```

All of which suggests that the reason you are getting no records returned lies elsewhere. For example:

- Is there **definitely** at least one document in your collection which has date_added > `T-15d`?
- Does your query, perhaps, contain other criteria which might cause the relevant documents to be excluded?
- Is `data_added` **definitely** a ISODate in the documents in the collection you are querying?

Comment: I am not sure why but it works now, I tried your version and its all good now. Thanks