# Find upcoming birthday from the array of date

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have array of dates childrendob like

```
[
    "2000-01-21T15:18:49+05:30",
     "2008-03-12T15:18:49+05:30"
 ]
```

I want to fetch data from users table in which the children birthday is after 7 days from today.
Like suppose today is 15 Jan and result should be all users for which childrendob is 21-1
I need mongodb query for this

Comment: Hi, Sorry if I explaned wrong. I need mongo query for this

Comment: @saching please go through this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29524555/find-records-from-7-days-ago-from-now-in-mongodb

Comment: @sachin why its in array, a children have 2 or more birth dates?

Comment: @turivishal but user can have more than 1 child

Comment: ohk the dates are in ISO date format in collection?

Comment: @sachin Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not.

Answer (score 0):

- Get month and day after 7 days from your client side,

```
let date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7); // add 7 days in current date
let month = date.getMonth() + 1; // month
let day = date.getDate(); // date
```

- `$filter` to iterate loop of `dates` array, check `$and` condition from month and day,
- `$toDate` to convert string date to ISO date, it its already in ISO date then you can skip/remove this conversation
- `$month` to get month from date
- `$dayOfMonth` to get date form date
- `$match` for dates should not be empty

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      dates: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$dates",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              { $eq: [{ $month: { $toDate: "$$this" } }, month] }, // input month variable
              { $eq: [{ $dayOfMonth: { $toDate: "$$this" } }, day] } // input day variable
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $match: { dates: { $ne: [] } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aHVqkO-w9xp)

Comment: My answer needs to be modified, i removed it. It might have led wrong. Since you posted it, i dont post it again. Thank you.